# Taking pictures using camera and applying image filters to the picture But filters are taking time to apply on to the image

Tags: ios, uiimage, ciimage

Taking  pictures using camera and applying image filters to the picture But filters are taking time to apply on to the image. filters are very slow. Anyone can suggest the less time taking filters.

I have implemented the filters using following link.
    https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters.

please suggest me the fastest way like Instagram filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very old repo. I suggest taking a look at [GPUImage](https://github.com/bradlarson/gpuimage/). All the effects are performed on the GPU, and as a result, are very fast... enough for filtering live video.

Comment: Is it possible to make all filters like instagram by GPUImage?